# $\operatorname{NEF}(X)\subset\operatorname{Big}(X)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Does there exist a smooth projective variety $X$ such that $\operatorname{NEF}(X)-\{0\}$ is strictly contained in $\operatorname{Big}(X)$, where $\operatorname{Big}(X)$ is the interior of $\overline{\operatorname{Eff}(X)}$?

Comment: 1) The nef cone, by definition, is closed.                          

2) The surface $\mathbb{F}_n$ carries a curve $B$ with $B^2=-n$, and a big class $H$ whith $H\cdot B=0$. The class $H+B$ is big but not nef, since $(H+B)\cdot B=-n$.

Comment: @abx for example, when $n=1$, $\mathbb{F}_1=\mathrm{Bl}_{pt}(\mathbb{P}^2)$, we have $(-1)$ curve $E$ and big class $L$. Then $\mathrm{Eff}(\mathbb{F}_1)=\langle E, L-E \rangle$ and $\mathrm{NEF}(\mathbb{F}_1)=\langle L,L-E \rangle$, in this case I think we do not have an example where $\overline{\mathrm{NEF}}-\{0\}\subset \mathrm{int}(\overline{\mathrm{Eff}})$ (as they share an common edge)?

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, my example is wrong — I didn't read your question carefully.

Comment: @abx Sorry I should state that more clearly, so we have two cones $\mathrm{NEF}$ and $\mathrm{Eff}$ in $\mathrm{N}^1$. We know $\mathrm{NEF}\subset\overline{\mathrm{Eff}}$, and I am looking for an example that their boundary are disjoint? (Or the cone $\mathrm{NEF}$ is contained in the interior of $\overline{\mathrm{Eff}}$, which is $\mathrm{Big}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably someone will come up with a simpler example, but here's a Calabi-Yau threefold that fits the bill: look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1649.pdf .  Use the example given in section 6.  The Picard rank is 2, the nef cone is given in Prop 6.1, and the rays on the boundary of the movable cone are computed in Lemma 6.7.  In this case the nef cone is strictly contained in the movable cone, which is a subcone of the pseudoeffective cone in general, although in this example they should agree.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a perhaps simpler example: let $S$ be a general quartic surface containing a conic $C$. Then $\operatorname{Pic}(S) $ is spanned by the hyperplane section $H$ and the conic $C$. The intersection form on $\operatorname{Pic}(S) $ does not represent 0, so every nonzero nef class is big. However the class $H+kC$, for $k\geq 2$, is big but not nef.

Comment: I guess that taking a plane $P$ containing $C$, the residual to $C$ in the intersection $P \cap S$ is another conic $C'$ whose class $H-C$ spans the other extremal ray of the effective cone.

Comment: @abx Thanks for the answer! Would you explain why $\mathrm{Pic}(S)=\langle H,C \rangle$?

Comment: In this case, we have $\mathrm{NEF}=\langle H+C, 2H-C\rangle$, which indeed lies in the interior of $\overline{Eff}=\langle C, H-C \rangle$.

Comment: @abx Would you say a little bit more about the claim $\mathrm{Pic}(S)=\langle H,C\rangle$? For example (1) Is it a special argument for K3 surfaces? (2)How do we argue in char $p$? Thanks!

Comment: It is a classical fact for surfaces in $\Bbb{P}^3$. I will try to find a reference.

Comment: A good reference is the thesis of A. F. Lopez:
*Noether-Lefschetz theory and the Picard group of projective surfaces.*
Mem. Amer. Math. Soc.438 (1991).